# Google Apps Script Sheet extract numbers as string

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I'm new to Google apps script and i'm trying to extract from a sheet a range of numbers but i want to extract them as string the way they are written on the sheet.
I used the `getValues()`  function as such but the numbers are getting formatted example `12` becomes `12.0` and long ints like `14500536` becomes `14500536E7`

```
  var X=sheet.getSheets()[0].getRange(5,1,lastrow-4);
  var rawX=X.getValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
var rawX=X.getDisplayValues();
```